# Function is acting asynchronous when it is in a synchronous environment

Tags: node.js, express

So i have an express server that im using to build and learn about API usage and stuff, and when it calls an API key validation function (which calls from a sql server and validates the permissions are correct)

I've narrowed it down to this function

check_api_key_permissions is the function that checks if a supplied api key is allowed
parameters: response, api_key, permissions (array)

**GET request to URL function** *This is shortened a tad bit but still has the area causing the issue*

```js
function get_upload(req, res, next)
{
    var file;
    
    console.log(key);
    
    console.log("running")
    var valid = check_api_key_permissions(res, "master", ["view"]);

    setTimeout(() => {
      valid = true;
    }, 1000);

    console.log("ran");

    console.log(valid);
    console.log("permissions: " + valid);
}
```

Now i get the following output on my server:

```
1: master
2: running
3: ran
4: undefined
5: permissions: undefined
[
  TextRow {
    apikey: 'master',
    permissions: '*',
    assigned: 'never',
    active: '1'
  }
]
```

i numbered it so its easier to reference. lines 1 - 5 is the get_upload function. the next line is the object returned from the sql database. this shows that its running and async runs the check_api_key_permissions and it finishes after

**Could just be me but im not sure**

Comment: What exactly is the question?  `setTimeout()` is asynchronous so, of course, it would behave that way.  We can't see the code to `check_api_key_permissions()` to comment on it.

Comment: @jfriend00 the question was why is it executing the next lines if the first function hasnt finished and returned a result inside the synchronous function

Comment: Which line of code executes before you expect it to?  Please be specific about what you expect to see.  If you're wondering why it continues before `check_api_key_permissions()` is done, then show us that function's code!  If you're wondering why things continue before `setTimeout()` calls its callback, then that's because `setTimeout()` is non-blocking and asynchronous and the interpreter does not wait for it to finish.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1Ddp7Hjr theres the function, i was just using timeout as a test, but still i tried the function with async and doing await on the function and it still got skipped over

Comment: Well, your question needs to code for that function in it directly to be a complete question since, as it turns out, the entire question is really about the `check_api_key_permissions()` function implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `check_api_key_permissions()` is asynchronous, yet it does NOT have any sort of asynchronous interface to it so the caller has no idea when it is actually done executing and has no idea what it's eventual asynchronous result is.

Instead, you have a synchronous interface to it.  It MUST either return a promise that resolves only when it is done and resolves with the final value or it must take a callback that gets called when its done.  And, it needs a way to communicate back errors in addition to success.

As your code currently stands, `check_api_key_permissions()` just starts an asynchronous operation and then immediately returns with no return value.  Then some time later (after it's already returned), the callback to your database gets called, you process that callback and return a value and that return value just goes back into some database code somewhere and is completely ignored.  You need an asynchronous interface on `check_api_key_permissions()` so the caller can know when it's actually done and can get it's final resolved value.  Personally, I would use promises and I'd use the promise interface in your database instead of the callback interface too.

Comment: lifesaver man, thank you so much, sorry for the initial confusion